Maximum coins with one Counterfeit coin among them that can be determined in 3 weighings given that the coin can be heavier or lighter
What is the largest number of coins from which one can detect a counterfeit in three weighings with a pan balance, if it is known in advance only that the counterfeit coin differs in weight from the other coins?
----Zorich Mathematical Analysis I 2.2 Exercise 28 b)
I have seen one answer online saying that:

To find the largest number of coins we can detect a counterfeit from, in 3 weighings, we can perform the following steps:

Consider the fact that we have three possible outcomes for each weighing: Left side is heavier, right side is heavier, or both sides are balanced.
As there are 3 weighings, the total number of possible outcomes is
which is 27 possible outcomes.
Keep in mind that one of these outcomes is "all weighings are balanced." This outcome corresponds to all the genuine coins being weighed. So, we have 26 distinct outcomes remaining for the coins with different weights.
Divide the remaining outcomes into two groups, one for the heavier counterfeit coin and one for the lighter counterfeit coin. There will be
outcomes in each group.
In each group, there are 13 outcomes. We can detect the counterfeit coin among 13 coins in each group. 6. In total, we can detect a counterfeit coin among
coins. Hence, the largest number of coins from which we can detect a counterfeit coin in three weighings with a pan balance is 26 coins.


But I think the proof is unrigorous, so I want to ask for a rigorous solution to it.
Also the subquestion prior to this subquestion states that there is a one to one correspondence between unbalanced ternary numbers to ternary numbers.That is, every $(\alpha_n\alpha_{n-1}\cdots \alpha_0)_3,\alpha_i\in\{0,1,2\}$ can be converted to $(\beta_m\beta_{m-1}\cdots\beta_0)_3,\beta\in\{-1,0,1\}$
Edit:
And here is my solution to it:
There are $3^3$ possibilities for weighings and they can't be all same, then $3^3-1$, and then we have the possibility being divided over to heavier counterfeit coins and lighter counterfeit coins, and thus we have $\frac{3^3-1}{2}=13$
But I find it unrigorous and doubt if it is right.

Welcome to Mathematics StackExchange. Please include your efforts and where you are stuck. As a hint, how much information does a single weighing provide, and how much information does one need to identify the counterfeit coin?

@K.Jiang What does information supposed to mean? I don't really understand, but I noticed that it might be related to conversion of unbalanced ternary number to balanced ternary number.

@K.Jiang is that there are $3^3$ possibilities for weighings and they can't be all same, then $3^3-1$, and then we have the possibility being divided over to heavier counterfeit coins and lighter counterfeit coins, and thus we have $\frac{3^3-1}{2}=13$

There's a classic solution for $12$ coins so that's known to be solvable.  The argument above establishes that the answer can't be greater than $13$, but it doesn't establish that there is, in fact, some sequence of weighings that will always allow you to identify the counterfeit coin among $13$.

@OwenA. Your argument is mostly correct; however: "and they can't all be the same" - not exactly. All $3$ weighings can be the same. Really, the maximum number of coins that can be analyzed in $N$ weighings (when it is known that exactly one is false) is $\lfloor \frac{3^N}{2} \rfloor$; you will find this to be equivalent to your expression.

@K.Jiang Can you write an answer about the rationale for this answer, it would be helpful for people viewing this question, thank you.

There are two problems with your proof:

There is no reason why not every weighting could be balanced.
You have to argue why heavier and lighter conterfeits give different results.

Both are not hard to fix. There are $3^3$ possible results. If we weigh the counterfeit coin, we will always know if it was lighter or heavier, so every coin besides one corresponds to two possible results, so we need $2(N-1)+1$ results, in other words, $N≤\frac{3^3+1}2 = 14$.
This is in fact the solution if you have a 15th reference coin which you know is not fake, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3932602/1252877 using unbalanced ternary numbers. The problem, however, is that without using the reference coin, you would have to weigh an odd number of coins.
To show this, note that there are 3^2 = 9 sequences starting with 0, including the 000 sequence, so there would be 5 coins that are not weighed in the first step. There are $2\cdot 3^2 = 18$ sequences starting with plus or minus, so there would be 9 coins that are weighed in the first step. This is not possible, so you can't weigh 14 coins.
But 13 coins is possible, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balance_puzzle#Variations. Alternatively, note that using the first 13 rows in the aforementioned answer solves the problem, too.

The 13-coin case is ambiguous: You can always determine the counterfeit coin but not always whether it's heavier or lighter.
The 13-coin solution goes as follows: Divide the coins into two groups of four $\{A,B,C,D\},\{E,F,G,H\}$ and the remaining group of five $\{I,J,K,L,M\}$. Weigh the two groups of four agsinst each other with $\{A,B,C,D\}$ on the left and $\{E,F,G,H\}$ on the right. Then rearrange the groups by cyclically permuting three three-coin subgroups, so that in the second weighing $\{D,I,J,K\}$ is on the left and $\{A,B,C,H\}$ is on the right.

If both weighings are balanced, then the counterfeit is in ${\L,M\}$.

If the first weighing only is balanced, then the counterfeti is in $\{I,J,K\}$ and whether it is heavier or lighter is known.

If the second weighing only is balanced, then the counterfeti is in $\{E,F,G\}$ and whether it is heavier or lighter is known.

If both weighings are unbalanced in the same direction then the counterfeit is in $\{D,H\}$.

If both weighings are unbalanced in opposite directions then the counterfeit is in $\{A,B,C\}$ and whether it is heavier or lighter is known.


In all cases we enter the final weighing with with two unknowns or three unknowns with the direction of bias given, and in both of these scenarios the final weighing can be designed accordingly.
However, if the first result above applies (counterfeit in ${\L,M\}$ then only one of these coins enters the final weighing and if the counterfeit happens to be the other, we never know whether it's heavier or lighter.
